# How to properly account for WCAG name, state, value, and role when using an icon as a toggle button

Tags: html, css, button, wcag

Frequently I'm faced with the task of using material icons and turning them into interactive buttons. For instance, there might be an icon that when clicked reveals text and rotates. When it's clicked again it rotates back to the original position and the text disappears.

```
<div onClick={toggleButton()}>
  <i
    role="toggle button"
    aria-pressed="true"
    alt="Toggle text"
    class="material-icons"
  >
    toggle_off
  </i>
  Random text...
</div>

<div onClick={toggleButton()}>
  <i
    role="toggle button"
    aria-pressed="true"
    alt="Toggle text"
    class="material-icons"
  >
    toggle_on
  </i>
</div>

-an if conditional would render either of these divs based on pressed or not pressed
```

Typically, I handle this button adding a role, aria-state, and alt text to the material icon and change the aria-state when clicked. However, I always feel that I might not be doing this as effectively as I should.

What is the proper way to make something like an icon used as a toggle button accessible?

(I know that best practice for WCAG (web accessibility) is to use a button component, but because of the unique nature of material icons that's not possible.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You'll need to change a few things:

1. `role="toggle button"` should be `role="button"`
2. Beginning with `aria-pressed="true"` is fine if your default button state is pressed. Otherwise, its initial value should be `false`
3. Get rid of `alt`, as it doesn't belong here. If you're including text in your icon (as in your example code), you don't need to replace anything. Otherwise, use `aria-label` and put your button text there
4. Add `tabindex="0"` so that your icon can be reached by keyboard

### Event handling

To make your icon behave like a real button, you'll also need to listen for keys like the space-bar and enter key. These keystrokes should be treated as clicks, as a real button would.

```
const el = document.querySelector('my-icon');

el.addEventListener('keypress', handleKeyPress);
el.addEventListener('click', handleClick);

function handleClick() { 
  // Update aria-pressed
}

function handleKeyPress(e) {
  // Handle space-bar and enter key
}
```

So, in the end, your toggle icon button might look something like this:

```
<i
  role="button"
  aria-pressed="false"
  class="material-icons"
>
  Button text
</i>
```

or (sans visible button text):

```
<i
  role="button"
  aria-pressed="false"
  aria-label="Button text"
  class="material-icons"
></i>
```